# How to refresh an Infragistics UltraGrid?

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am using Infragistics UltraGrid with datasouce Windows Bindingsouce.
On change, I provide datasouce to Bindingsouce and call DataBinding of UltraGrid. Value in the datasouce of Bindingsouce changes, but that is not reflected in the UltraGrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding source must raise some event to trigger grid refresh. For example, if you are using `BindingList` it should raise the `ListChanged` event.

Answer (score 2):

Also, make sure that whatever class that you are using as your Binding Object implements INotifyPropertyChanged so that when you update the BindingObject at run time it gets channeled to BindingSource which eventually gets picked up by Grid.

i.e.:

```
BindingList<Foo> lstItems = new BindingList<Foo>;
BindingSource bso = ;
bso.DataSource = lstItems; 
Grid.DataSource = bso; 

public class Foo :  INotifyPropertyChanged
```

[see MDSN article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx)

Also depends if you changing the collection outside Grid (at runtime, because if you do, you need to use  `BindingList<T>` and assign it to `BindingSource`